# How can I use variables in other modules in python?

Tags: python

That's one.py:

```
test = {'1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]}
import two
two.example()
```

And that's two.py:

```
def example():
    print test[1][5]
```

Can you tell me why this will fail with the following error?

```
NameError: global name 'test' is not defined
```

Thanks!

Comment: `import` in Python is nothing like `include` in other languages. `import two` creates a module object singleton called `two` whose contents is initialized from the code in two.py. It doesn't copy the contents of "two.py" into the parse stream!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can import it in the function

```
def example():
    from one import test
    print test[1][5]
```

Or you can pass test in as a variable

```
#one.py
two.example(test)

#two.py
def example(test):
    print test[1][5]
```

Comment: The `import` inside the function will work bad! That print statement will be executed more than one time.

Comment: No, it will not be imported multiple times. Modules are only executed once; after that, the already-imported module is used.

Comment: @kindall: It seems to me that `one.py` is going to be executed: `$ python one.py`, so the function `example()` will be called twice, hence the number `6` will be also printed twice! *Import from a module that will execute "main code" without the `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement is bad.* And since I would not suggest to import from your main file and I would not suggest either to use 3 files for 5 lines of code, my point remains: **that mutual import is a bad advice**.

Comment: @RikPoggi You're correct that without `if __name__ == '__main__'` it will be printed twice.

This entire layout of this program is bad but it answers his question. There are many other ways I'd do this instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because your two.py doesn't know what `test` is, you should pass that as a parameter to `example`:

one.py:

```
test = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
import two
two.example(test)
```

two.py:

```
def example(test):
    print test[1][5]
```

**Note:** I took the liberty to change your `test` dict entry from `'1'` to `1` since you called `test[1][5]` and not `test['1'][5]`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, everything is an object. *Even modules*.

`test` is an attribute of the `one` module object, not the `two` module object. So in the code of `two`, it's not in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Every module (including the text of your script) has its own namespace for global variables ([global symbol table](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)). It is possible to access the other module's variables, but not that easy. Furthermore, usually a better way would be to pass them as function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import one.py in your two.py file, for it to be in the namespace.

Two.py:

```
from one import *
print test
```

Comment: If one.py is used as a module, this will work; otherwise (if run as a script), the one.py will be executed the second time, this time as a module, which is likely not what is needed.

Comment: @Tanriol was quickly writing it on an iPhone. The one.py should have `if name == "__main__": #do something ` then it would be run as planned.

Comment: @julio.alegria depends if you want it in your namespace or not. The reason `from xxx import *` is not good practice is that you get a whole lot of other things in the namespace, but since he wants the files to act as though they where actually just one file, `from xxx import *` would make more sense.